# how can i make the input field to be empty after i click a button?

Tags: javascript

i tried using `userinput.value = ''` at the end of function but the input is still not empty. here is the code that i've tried

```
let input = document.querySelector('input')
let list = document.querySelector('ul')
let button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', addtodo)

function addtodo() {
  let userinput = input.value
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  li.innerText = userinput
  list.appendChild(li)
  // console.log(this)
  console.log(userinput)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the value of the input with `input.value = ""`

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input')
let list = document.querySelector('ul')
let button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', addtodo)

function addtodo() {
  let userinput = input.value
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  li.innerText = userinput
  list.appendChild(li)
  input.value = ""
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<ul></ul>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: any idea why `console.log(userinput === input.value)` in this case i need to use `input.value` instead of just `userinput` which is just the same as `input.value`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Helps :)

```
    let input = document.querySelector('input')
    let list = document.querySelector('ul')
    let button = document.querySelector('button')

    button.addEventListener('click', addtodo)

    function addtodo() {
      let userinput = input.value
      let li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerText = userinput
      list.appendChild(li)
      // console.log(this)
      input.value = ''
      console.log(userinput)
    }
```

Comment: any idea why `console.log(userinput === input.value)` in this case i need to use `input.value` instead of just `userinput` which is just the same as `input.value`?

Comment: can you please explain what you're try to say?

Comment: if i write `userinput = ''`, it will not work, when i try `console.log(userinput === input.value)` i get true. i can only use `input.value = ''` for the code to work https://imgur.com/gOcgNHr

Comment: `userinput` is a variable and `input`  is object of `document.querySelector('input')` that's why. you can perform every possible action with input with `input`  object

Comment: please check `console.log(typeof(userinput));  console.log(typeof(input));` I hope this helps

Comment: got it, thank you.. its clearer now